# uncheck a checkbox which is checked and freezed with a condition in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, html-table

I have a table that iterates on JSON values, i have checkbox in the first column

requirement: when 5 checkboxes are selected, the user shouldn't be able to select the 6th checkbox, but he can deselect any in the 5 checkboxes

current scenario: i am able to freeze the checkboxes when the user selects 5 checkboxes but it isn't allowing me to deselect the selected checkbox

```
<checkbox [forbidden]="isFull() && !Selected" [ngModel]="Selected" (ngModelChange)="Change(Result, $event)"></checkbox>
```

checkbox is a custom component in my code base

```
isFull() {
    return someService.Slots()===0; // availableSlots returns 5
}

Change(Result, $event){
    // some code irrelevant to the checkbox logic
    // Result holds the JSON value for iterating row
}
```

Please provide a working plunker or any online editor for better understanding

Thanks in advance

Comment: also try asking here may be you get answer https://t.me/angularhelps

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't be "isFull() && !Selected"? because you want to freeze unselected ones, but still are able to deselect the selected ones.

Comment: That is a typo from my end, even after changing that doesn't works any thoughts? I corrected the question

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you!, You can optimize this and modified according to your need.

> Working sample [plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/SJuxti3xuH3KerXk?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

Template file:

```
 template: `
          <ul>
            <ng-container>
                <li *ngFor="let item of list">
                <input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    value="{{item.value}}"
                    [disabled]="item.disabled"
                     (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, item)"
                    /> 
                    {{item.label}}<br>
                </li>
            </ng-container>
          </ul>
         <pre> {{checkedList | json}} </pre>
        `
```

Class file

```
 export class App {
        name: string;
        checkedList: any = [];
        list: any = [
            {'label': 'A', 'value': 'a', 'disabled': false},
            {'label': 'B', 'value': 'b', 'disabled': false},
            {'label': 'C', 'value': 'c', 'disabled': false},
            {'label': 'D', 'value': 'd', 'disabled': false},
            {'label': 'E', 'value': 'e', 'disabled': false},
            {'label': 'F', 'value': 'f', 'disabled': false},
            {'label': 'G', 'value': 'g', 'disabled': false}
        ];
        constructor() {

        }

        onCheckboxChange(e, item) {

            if(e.target.checked) {
                this.checkedList.push(item);
            } else {
                let index = this.checkedList.findIndex(obj => item.value === obj.value);
                if(index > -1) {
                    this.checkedList.splice(index,1);
                }
            }

            if(this.checkedList.length > 4) {  // *change available slots*
                let unCheckedList = this.list.filter((obj) => {
                   let isCheck = this.checkedList.find((item) => {
                        return item.value === obj.value
                    }); 
                    obj.disabled = !isCheck ? true : false;
                    return !isCheck;
                });
            } else {
               this.list.map((obj)=>{
                   obj.disabled = false;
               });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

#### UPDATE

Try this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { list } from './list';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  list: Array<any>;
  checked = [];
  shouldCheckboxesBeDisabled = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = list;
    this.recheckDisablingStatus();
  }

  recheckDisablingStatus() {
    this.shouldCheckboxesBeDisabled = this.list.filter(item => item.checked).length >= 5;
  }

  uncheckIfAlreadyChecked(itemIndex) {
    const isChecked = this.list[itemIndex].checked;
    this.list[itemIndex].checked = isChecked ? false : isChecked;
    this.recheckDisablingStatus();
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Checked</td>
    <td>Uncheck if Already Checked</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input 
          [disabled]="shouldCheckboxesBeDisabled && !list[i].checked"
          type="checkbox" 
          [(ngModel)]="list[i].checked"
          (change)="recheckDisablingStatus()">
      </td>
      <td><button (click)="uncheckIfAlreadyChecked(i)">Uncheck If Checked</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awjiwj?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Give this a try:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Checked</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of list$ | async; let i = index">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input 
          [disabled]="shouldCheckboxesBeDisabled && checked.indexOf(item.id) < 0"
          type="checkbox" 
          (change)="onCheckBoxChange(item.id, $event.target.checked)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And in your Component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  list$: Observable<Array<any>>;
  checked = [];
  shouldCheckboxesBeDisabled = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.list$ = this.http.get<Array<any>>('/assets/data.json');
    this.list$ = of([
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Name 1",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Name 2",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Name 3",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Name 4",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Name 5",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Name 6",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: "Name 7",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: "Name 8",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        name: "Name 9",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "Name 10",
        checked: true
      }
    ]);
  }

  onCheckBoxChange(itemId, checked) {
    if(checked) {
      this.checked.push(itemId);
    } else {
      const itemIndexToRemove = this.checked.indexOf(itemId);
      this.checked.splice(itemIndexToRemove, 1);
    }
    this.shouldCheckboxesBeDisabled = this.checked.length >= 5;
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7n1yxa?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: i appreciate your assistance, could you please do one more thing? if i pass id value it should check if the checkbox is selected, if selected deselect that                Thank you so much

Comment: Hi there, I'm sorry but I didn't quite understand what you meant by the comment above. Did you mean that the checked state of the checkbox would be present in the data and I have to initially load it with that checked value? What I mean is, let's say the `checked` state of Name 3 item is true, you want Checkbox three in the table to be checked. Is that what you meant?

Comment: from TS if i have the  "id" column value, i need a logic that would check the respective checkbox has been checked, if checked then uncheck the same

Comment: And what happens if it's not checked? Make it checked? Or do nothing?

Comment: do nothing if unchecked

Comment: @zuberalisavanur, I've updated my answer. Please check if that helps.